# Hamiltonian Path in Haskell

Tags: haskell, path

I don't know how to make a function that given a list of list , for example:

> [[0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,0],[1,1,0,1],[0,0,0,0]]

that means that the first one can go to the 2nd and 3rd, the node 2, can go to the 3rd , the 3rd node can go to the 1st, 2nd and 4th, and the 4th node can't go to any one, **So, I want to make a function in haskell, that given that kind of list of list (only 0's and 1's) return a Bool if I find a hamiltonian path, that means if you can visit all the nodes**

Answer (score 2):

Hamiltonian path is a path through the graph that visit each node exactly once. The simplest and most naïve way to find one would be to actually try all possible permutations of the nodes and for each such path check if it is Hamiltonian.

In order to write such function, try to decompose the problem.

First write a function that will check if there is an edge between two nodes: `hasEdge :: [[Int]] -> Int -> Int -> Bool`.

Another useful function will check that a path is Hamiltonian: `isHamiltonian :: [[Int]] -> [Int] -> Bool`. Assume the second argument is a list of node numbers where each node is exactly once, therefore you only have to verify that each subsequent pair in the list represents an edge in the graph.

Now all that is left is to generate all permutations of list `[0..(length ps - 1)]` and check if any satisfy the `isHamiltonian` predicate. You migth find the function [`permutations`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:permutations) from `Data.List` very useful here.

This approach will obviously be very slow, but that is kind of to be expected for an NP-hard problem. Anyway, it may be a good start before implementing better algorithm.